# SQL delete trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-trigger

I have 3 tables:

POS(IDPOS, IDCARD);

CARDS(IDCARD, IDPERSON);

PERSON(IDPERSON, PERSONTYPE).

Every time a card is associated to a POS, I need to ensure that the person that has that card can only be PERSONTYPE='Employee' or PERSONTYPE='Volunteer'.
This is what I accomplished so far, but it doesn't seem to be working when I insert valid records.

```
DELETE POS
FROM inserted i 
INNER JOIN POS p ON i.IDPOS=p.IDPOS
INNER JOIN CARDS ON i.IDCARD=CARDS.IDCARD
INNER JOIN PERSON ON CARDS.IDPERSON=PERSON.IDPERSON
WHERE PERSONTYPE <> 'Employee' or PERSONTYPE <> 'Volunteer';
```

This trigger is done on the POS table and is an after insert, update.

Does someone know were is the mistake?

Comment: WHERE PERSONTYPE <> 'Employee' or PERSONTYPE <> 'Volunteer'; will become WHERE PERSONTYPE <> 'Employee' AND PERSONTYPE <> 'Volunteer';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NOT IN`:

```
WHERE PERSONTYPE NOT IN ('Employee', 'Volunteer');
```

Your logic requires an `AND`, not `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have used alias for POS, you need to put alias for delete. Also you can use `NOT EXISTS()` instead of joining another table :

with alias usage :

```
DELETE P
FROM POS AS P 
INNER JOIN INSERTED AS I ON i.IDPOS=p.IDPOS
INNER JOIN CARDS ON I.IDCARD=CARDS.IDCARD
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                    FROM PERSON 
                    WHERE CARDS.IDPERSON=PERSON.IDPERSON 
                    AND PERSONTYPE IN ('Employee','Volunteer')
                 );
```

normal usage :

```
DELETE 
FROM POS
INNER JOIN INSERTED AS I ON I.IDPOS=POS.IDPOS
INNER JOIN CARDS ON I.IDCARD=CARDS.IDCARD
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                    FROM PERSON 
                    WHERE CARDS.IDPERSON=PERSON.IDPERSON 
                    AND PERSONTYPE IN ('Employee','Volunteer')
                 );
```